# perl pattern matching one by one and process it

Tags: perl, pattern-matching, substitution

I have a string

```
[something]text1[/something] blah blah [something]text2[/something]
```

I need to write a Perl script to read what is in the `[something]` tag, process it to "text-x", and put it back with an `[otherthing]` tag. So the above string should be

```
[otherthing]text-1[/otherthing] blah blah [otherthing]text-2[/otherthing]
```

Processing "textx" to "text-x" is not one step process.

So this is solution that I have till now:

```
m/[something](?<text>.*)[/something]/
```

This will get me the string in between and I can process that to "text-x" but how do I put it back in the same place with `[otherthing]text-x[/otherthing]`?

1. How do I use s/// in this case?
2. How to do it for the whole string one by one ?

Comment: That regex will not work, since `[`, `]` and `/` are unescaped meta characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `/e` switch on `s///` to evaluate the right hand side before using the result as the substitution, and the `/g` flag to do this for every match.

Here is a simple example:

```
use 5.12.0;

my $str = ">1<  >2<  >34<";

$str =~ s/>(\d+)</">>".process("$1")."<<"/eg;

say $str;

sub process {
    return "x" x $_[0];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should come close. It uses the /e modifier to allow you to do processing in the replacement side of the regex and so it calls the fix_textx function where you can do multiple steps.

The normal way of iterating over matches is with the /g modifier.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = '[something]text1[/something] blah blah [something]text2[/something]';

$string =~ s{\[something\](text[^[]*)\[\/something\]}
            {'[otherthing]' . fix_textx($1) . '[/otherthing]'}ge;

print $string;

sub fix_textx {
    my ($testx) = @_;
    $testx =~ s/text\K(.*)/-$1/;
    return $testx;
}
```

**EDIT:** fixed the square bracket. Thanks @tadmc

Comment: Your square bracket in your char class is facing the wrong way, it should be (text[^[]*).

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, you can accomplish what you're trying to do by splitting the string on `"[something]"` and then processing the beginning of each piece (except the first one), then joining the pieces back together when you're done.

I don't know if there is a general way to iterate over the regex matches in a string in Perl. I'm hoping someone else will answer this question and educate me on that.